# How do I get my audible books in my iTunes library as .aa files to be .m4p files?

Tags: audio, ipad

How do I get my audible books in my iTunes library as `.aa` files to be `.m4p` files?  My new iPad 2 won't recognize the `.aa`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume we're talking about books in Audible.com's proprietary format?  If so, Audible lets you re-download the books in alternative formats even if you have let your subscription expire.  So login to Audible and see if a better download format is available.